# Java Basics - Extract digits from a number

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I'm new to Java, so still trying to figure out the syntax and code execution,

I'm working on a very simple algorithm which is basically to return/print true or false statement if a  number is divisible by the  sum of its digits.

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            divisableNumber();
            
        }
        
        
        static void divisableNumber() {
            int num = 2250;
            int sumOfDigits  = 0;
            
            while (num > 0) {
                System.out.println(num);
                int remainder = num %10 ;
                sumOfDigits += remainder;
                System.out.println("line17");
                System.out.println(sumOfDigits);
                num = num /10;
            }
            
            System.out.println(num);
            
//          if(num % sumOfDigits == 0) {
//              System.out.println(  num);
//          } else {
//              System.out.println(num + "is not divisable by sum of digits");
//          }
            
        }
        
        //*****Explanation*********
//      java divides by 10 without remainder.
//      Hence, can see that with each iteration number is losing its unit digit( it happens end of each loop line21)
//      basically with each iteration we are checking what is the remainder of the input divided by 10
//      Eventually, we are adding the remainder ( which is the unit digit at each iteration)
    }

``
I don't understand why the loop zeros out the variable and how to overcome it ( i could have written another variable inside the loop , but it seems not clean ).
Can anyone help ?

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZbOW.png
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code prints 0 every time since it divides the number to 10 until it becomes 0 inside the `while` loop. Remember that any positive number below 10 divided by 10 gives the result 0 in Java.

You calculated the sum of digits correctly but did not check if it divides the number correctly. In order to achieve that, you need to store a copy of number at the start and check if it is divisible by `sumOfDigits`.

You can achieve the solution with the following code, it is very similar but structured a little better.

```
class Main
{
 
    // Function to check if the
    // given number is divisible
    // by sum of its digits
    static String divisableNumber(long n)
    {
        long temp = n; // store a copy of number
     
        // Find sum of digits
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0)
        {
            int k = (int) n % 10; // get remainder of division of 10
            sum += k; // add digit sum
            n /= 10; // divide number by 10
        }
     
        // check if sum of digits divides n
        if (temp % sum == 0)
            return "YES";
     
        return "NO";
    }
     
    // This is where the execution begins always (main function)
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        long n = 123; // better to declare number here and give it as a parameter to function
        System.out.println(isDivisible(n)); // print the result of divisible or not
    }
}
```